# Ionic go back trigger on click of hardware back button of message app

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm using cordova-sms-plugin and open native sms app in my app but when i click on hardware back button on sms app it goes back to my app and then trigger ionic go back too i can't understand a issue why my app go back trigger when i click on sms app back button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that is an issue with the lib and I've seen that you have posted an issue on Github that is good.

As a temporary workaround, you could override the behavior of hardware back button with JavaScript just before launching the plugin and cancel this after going back to ionic.

Here is the code :

```
// priority 101 dismiss "Return to previous view" action
var priority = 101;
var deregisterFunction = $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(backCallback, priority);
sms.send(number, message, options, success, error);


function success () { 
    deregisterBackButton();
    alert('Message sent successfully'); 
};
function error(e) { 
    deregisterBackButton();
    alert('Message Failed:' + e); 
};

function backCallback() {
    // Do nothing
}

function deregisterBackButton() {
    // Timeout to be sure to don't have issue with back trigerring after
    // returning to view
    $timeout(function () {
        //Deregister
        deregisterFunction();
    }, 1000);
}
```

You need to inject `$ionicPlatform` and `$timeout` in the controller or service you use send.

For more infos about back button, you can view this link :
[ionic docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPlatform/)

Comment: I think i need to understand its not work with using hardware button and use a alternative like disable hardware on specified controller so thanks anyway its work like charm :)